# Html - reduce spacing between horizontal line & Image

Tags: html, css

I am developing an HTML based ui, as i am new to css so please suggest.
I want to format my UI so that spacing between the top & bottom line & button decreases.
Also the text to be moved little up so that it comes in center of alligned with button.

Please see the attached image, i have edited it and added arrow to it.

Also is it possible to replace multiple `&nbsp;` with some **single TAB** ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
background-color:#292B3B;
}
h1 {color:white;}
p  {color:#DDDFED; font-size:150%; text-indent:5px; align="middle"}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>My CSS web page!</h1>
<hr>

<p> 
<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" value="Submit" alt="Bulb pop up" width="48" height="48" /> 
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
Button One

</p>

<hr>


<p> 
<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" value="Submit" alt="Bulb pop up" width="48" height="48" /> 
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
Button Two

</p>

<hr>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/asSje/).

Comment: `is it possible to replace multiple &nbsp; with some single TAB`.. yes you can use `margin` or `padding`  css properties to the image. check my above fiddle and understand it.

Comment: @Mr_Green I will recommend your answer .. with padding: 10px; added to both <h1>  & <p>

Comment: but why thumb cursor does not comes or button border highlight when it is pressed.. ?

Comment: Katoch, please learn HTML and css.. you are not using any button element in your project. anyway, you can have a button effect by using pseudo selectors as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/asSje/1/). It is not exactly what you need because it is just for your understanding. :)

Comment: last solution from you i did not liked .. :-( .....I am learning HTML & CSS both ... check this one http://jsfiddle.net/mj5au/6/  .. it is perfect but only thing missing is how to remove multiple &nbsp; ?

Comment: Ok i did it .  ...  took this part of code  yours p>span {
    margin-left: 100px;
} and added to  Mr Alien code .. http://jsfiddle.net/mj5au/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not resetting the default `margin` and `padding` applied by the browser, so use the snippet below..

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5au/)

Or to have max consistent cross browser experience, you can use [CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

You will require the snippet below for aligning your image vertically centered..

```
input[type=image] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, <s>`align="middle"`</s> is incorrect, you should use `text-align: center;` instead.

---

Rounding up the entire thing...

[**Final Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5au/3/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color:#292B3B;
}

h1 {
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:150%;
    text-indent:5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type=image] {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Finl Demo solution worked for me but .. i am not able to remove multiple &nbps .. please suggest on this .

Comment: @Katoch You have no control over your HTML?

Comment: I am learning this language mostly been c++ UI developer ... so found something missing in my html ui ... will take some time to gain command.

Comment: Ok i did it .. combined the Mr_green & your answer .. http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/asSje/  ...  took this part of code & added to yours p>span {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

Comment: @Katoch yea that is fine, I didn't knew that you don't have control over HTML

Comment: yes i am going through http://www.w3schools.com/ tutorials .. but combining all that stuff together to become good Html UI developer will take some time for me. thanks.

Comment: @Alien Ok ... Any other good tutorial you will like to suggest ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated your css. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mj5au/6/)

```
input[type=image]{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```